PDF blob didn't display in web mobile screen in Laravel 7
I know maybe this question have been asked several times.
All I want to do is display the PDF Blob in mobile screen web browser. I have tried to use embed tag and iframe tag but none of them can work properly in mobile screen web browser. FYI, the embed and iframe tag is work very well in dekstop screen. This is my controller
public function read_file($id) {
        $findId = DB::connection('sqlsrv38')->table('kred_file_regulasi')->find($id);

        if (!$findId) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'File not found',
                'data' => null,
            ], 404);
        }

        $filePath = $findId->nama_path;

        if (!Storage::disk('ftp_edoc')->exists($filePath)) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'File not found on storage',
                'data' => $findId,
            ], 404);
        }

        try {
            $fileContent = Storage::disk('ftp_edoc')->get($filePath);

            return response($fileContent)
                ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
                ->header('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="' . $findId->nama_file . '"');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Error reading file: ' . $e->getMessage(),
                'data' => $findId,
            ], 500);
        }
    }

And this is my blade
    @extends('layouts.media2');
    
    @section('judule')
    <li class="fas fa-solid fa-user-nurse text-success"></li> Daftar File Regulasi Keperawatan
    @endsection
    
    @section('isine')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div>
                    <h4>Jenis Regulasi</h4>
                    <div>
                        @foreach ($jenis_regulasi as $item)
                            <button class="btn btn-success w-100 mb-2 btn-jenis-reg" data-id="{{ $item->id }}">
                                <small class="font-weight-bold">{{ $item->jenis_reg }}</small>
                            </button>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <h4>Nama Regulasi</h4>
                <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column" id="nama-file-container">
                    <h1 class="bg-info mb-2 w-100 h-75 display-4 p-2 rounded-lg text-center
                    " id="btn-nama-file">Pilih Jenis Regulasi</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
    
    @section('modal')
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-show-pdf" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <div>
                        <p class="modal-title text-bold" id="modal-title"></p>
                        <small class="text-gray" id="modal-subtitle"></small>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="kolom_saran" class="row d-flex flex-column mx-2"></div>
                    <embed id="pdf-frame" src="${url}" style="width: 100%; min-height: 450px;" frameborder="0" type="application/pdf"></embed>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
    
    @push('js-script')
    <script>
    // Toast library
    function infoToast(posisine,icone,infone) {
      const Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: posisine,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 3000
      });
    
      Toast.fire({
            icon: icone,
            title: infone
        });
    }
    
    function getFiles(dataId) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "{{ route('keperawatan_fetch_files') }}",
            data: {
                _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                dataId: dataId,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                var selectFileContainer = $('#nama-file-container');
                selectFileContainer.empty();
                response.forEach(function(file) {
                    selectFileContainer.append(
                        `<button class="btn btn-info mb-2 w-100 btn-show-pdf text-left" data-id="${file.id}" data-name="${file.nama_file}" data-wbm="${file.waktu_baca_min}">${file.nama_file}</button>`
                    );
                });
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('AJAX Error:', status, error);
            },
        });
    }
    
    function startRead() {
        var getTimeNow = new Date().toISOString();
        return getTimeNow;
    }
    
    function convertMiliseconds(text) {
        const split = text.split(" ");
        const value = parseInt(split[0]);
        const acuan = split[1];
    
        let miliseconds = 0;
        if(acuan.includes('menit')) {
            miliseconds = value * 60 * 1000;
        } else if (acuan.includes('jam')) {
            miliseconds = value * 3600 * 1000;
        }
        return miliseconds;
    }
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body').on('click', '.btn-jenis-reg', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var dataId = $(this).data('id');
                getFiles(dataId);
            });
    
            $('body').on('click', '.btn-show-pdf', function () {
            var mulai = startRead();
            var fileId = $(this).data('id');
            var fileName = $(this).data('name');
            var waktuBacaMin = $(this).data('wbm');
            var miliseconds = convertMiliseconds(waktuBacaMin);
    
            var isMobile = window.innerWidth <= 768;
    
            $.ajax({
                url: `{{ route('keperawatan_read', ':id') }}`.replace(':id', fileId),
                method: 'GET',
                data: {
                    fileId: fileId,
                    _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                },
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                xhrFields: {
                    responseType: 'blob'
                },
                success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                    var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    $('#kolom_saran').empty();
                    $('#modal-subtitle').text(`Tombol akan bisa diklik jika sudah memenuhi waktu minimal baca: ${waktuBacaMin}`)
    
                    let kolomSaran = `
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-2">
                            <input type="hidden" id="nama_file" value="${fileName}">
                            <input type="hidden" id="mulai" value="${mulai}">
                            <input type="hidden" id="nid_karyawan" value="{{ session('nidkaryawan') }}">
                            <input type="hidden" id="id_karyawan" value="{{ session('idkaryawane') }}">
                            <input type="hidden" id="id_unit_kerja" value="{{ session('unite_id') }}">
                            <textarea type="text" name="saran" id="saran" cols="80" rows="2" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Jika tidak ada saran dan masukkan, silahkan klik simpan untuk setor baca SPO"></textarea>
                            &nbsp;
                            <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-baca-spo" disabled>SIMPAN</button>
                        </div>`;
                    $('#kolom_saran').append(kolomSaran);
                    $('#modal-body').append(``)
    
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        $('#btn-baca-spo').removeAttr("disabled");
                    }, miliseconds);
    
                    $('#pdf-frame').attr('src', url);
                    $('#modal-title').text(fileName);
                    $('#modal-show-pdf').modal('show');
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                    alert('Error: ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    
        $('body').on('click', '#btn-baca-spo', function () {
        var id_jenis_kegiatan = 4;
        var topik = $('#nama_file').val();
        var id_peran = 1;
        var mulai = $('#mulai').val();
        var akhir = new Date().toISOString();
        var detail = $('#saran').val();
        let nid_karyawan = $('#nid_karyawan').val();
        let id_karyawan = $('#id_karyawan').val();
        var periode = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear(), 10);
        var id_unit_kerja = $('#id_unit_kerja').val();
        console.log(typeof akhir, typeof mulai);
        $.ajax({
            url: `{{ route('keperawatan_add_aktf_kompetensi') }}`,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                id_jenis_kegiatan: id_jenis_kegiatan,
                topik: topik,
                id_peran: id_peran,
                mulai: mulai,
                akhir: akhir,
                detail: detail,
                nid_karyawan: nid_karyawan,
                id_karyawan: id_karyawan,
                periode: periode,
                id_unit_kerja: id_unit_kerja,
                _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.statuseKd === 200) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#modal-show-pdf').modal('hide');
                    infoToast('top', 'success', response.message);
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                if (xhr.status === 422) {
                    infoToast('toast-top-full-width', 'error', 'Terdapat kesalahan input, pastikan anda belum pernah melakukan setor aktifitas kompetensi ini');
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
</script>
@endpush

And this is how it displayed in mobile screen

By the way, I'm using Laravel 7 and Bootstrap 4

Try this in your PHP:
public function read_file($id) {
  $findId = DB::connection('sqlsrv38')->table('kred_file_regulasi')->find($id);

  try {
    
    //GET THE CONTENT OF THE FILE
    $fileContent = Storage::disk('ftp_edoc')->get($filePath);
    
    //RETURN THE CONTENT OF THE FILE AS BASE64 ENCODED
    return response()->json([
      'error' => false,
      'b64_file' => base64_encode($fileContent)
    ]);
            
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      return response()->json([
        'error' => 'Error reading file: ' . $e->getMessage(),
        'data' => $findId,
      ], 500);
    }
}

And this in your javascript:
Generate a base64 data url from the returned data and set it as the src for your iframe.
$.ajax({
  url: `{{ route('keperawatan_read', ':id') }}`.replace(':id', fileId),
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json', // <----- EXPECT JSON SINCE ALL OF YOUR ERRORS RETURN JSON
  data: {
    fileId: fileId,
    _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
  },
  success: function(data) {

    //GENERATE A BASE64 DATA URL
    var url = "data:application/pdf;base64,"+data.b64_file;
    
    //SET THE URL AS THE SRC ATTRIBUTE OF THE IFRAME
    $('#pdf-frame').attr('src', url);                
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    alert('Error: ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText);
  }
});

